# Lubuntu 20.04, fresh upgrade. Login screen issues

Tags: lubuntu

Just spent a few hours last night upgrading my old laptop up to the newest 20.04.  The laptop seems to function fine but when logging in the desktop does not seem to load properly.

The login page never disappears and after that, any menu or tab that is opened is then left on-screen.  Also when minimizing programs,  it leaves the lines on the screen when it goes small.

I have tried restarting the graphics with no luck and nothing I can search for seems to be similar.

Just wondering is someone else has seen something similar.

Thanks

Comment: check `dmesg | less` for errors and fails regarding graphics hardware and driver. Check which hardware you have  and which driver that is in use. Add info in your posting (edit!)